# General trees traversal Breadth-first (using Queues)

Tags: tree, breadth-first-search

I have an issue and i'm a bit confused. It's actually about how to traverse a general tree (not a binary one) using breadth first search (using Queues). All I can find is about binary trees. Thank you beforehand

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm for a general tree should just be an abstraction of the binary one.  For example-

- Start at root
- Enqueue children
- Dequeue and check if you've found what you were looking for
- if not, repeat!